# GUI forms editor

Tags: python, visual-studio, user-interface, ide, ptvs

I recently installed PTVS as I come from C# and I am used to Visual Studio.
I though that PTVS had a GUI creation support like Windows Forms in C#, I am pretty disappointed as I need to program several Windows applications, and I like python.

Is there any plugin to add this functionality to PTVS? do they plan to program it in a near future?

To widen my question:
Does it exist a real windows application IDE in python, with an "easy" GUI designer like Visual Studio?

Before blaming me, you have to know that **I already tried BOA, Dabo, SPE Python Eclipse and Netbeans plugins**, without success... I don't want a 0.7 project version from 2007... Is there **something solid** in there? I can't find it

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I'm reading [here](http://pytools.codeplex.com/discussions/265245) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python) PTVS has WPF support if you use IronPython. Here's a page that may be helpful too http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming. Personally I'd use Qt with PyQt or PySide, you can use QtDesigner to make your forms.

Comment: Both of your solutions are great, I tried PTVS with WPF support and it is just what I was looking for thanks

Comment: I still have a question though, WPF is html code ? what is it exactly? a web app framework? I read  [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) but I am still confused

Answer (score 1):

I always thought [#develop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) was a good IDE with a good forms editor, if you're willing to use IronPython and .NET.